# How can I retrieve JSON after getting a response from another JSON (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Hopefully, the question title isn't too vague or confusing, but I will explain it here:

Basically, I am trying to learn more about APIs during my React.JS journey. The project is to obtain Weather Forecast info based on whatever location (I am doing it based on Postal Codes in Canada) you enter in the search box. I am using Axios specifically for this one, and I've come across a little problem.

I want the program to take the response from one API link, and then take specific data from that response to insert it into another API link. Then it will finally get the response from the new link. Hopefully, this isn't confusing as well. I tried different things, and still no luck, but I will put what I have tried recently below.

Here's what I did so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  
  // UseStates to change the variables
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [postalcode, setPostalCode] = useState('')
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(0)
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(0)

  // API Links
  const geocodingURL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/zip?zip=${postalcode},CA&limit=1&appid=7fe57d3d219cd9512845e116e4c353c5`
  const weatherURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&units=metric&appid=7fe57d3d219cd9512845e116e4c353c5`
  
  // Arrow Functions to retrieve the responses from the API Links
  const searchPostalCode = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      axios.get(geocodingURL).then((response) => {
        setData(response.data)
        console.log(response.data)
      })

      axios.get(weatherURL).then((response) => {
        setLatitude(data.lat)
        setLongitude(data.lon)
        setData(response.data)
        console.log(response.data)
      })

      setPostalCode("")
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="search">
        <input
          value={postalcode}
          onChange={event => setPostalCode(event.target.value) && setLatitude(data.lat) && setLongitude(data.lon)}
          onKeyPress={searchPostalCode}
          searchWeather
          placeholder='Enter Postal Code'
          type="text"/>
      </div>

      <!-- There is more code here, but I don't think it's necessary for this question since it's just header tags -->
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Weather API I'm using doesn't have a direct Location -> Weather API. I have to use two, so I have to do Location -> Longitude & Lattitude, and then Longitude & Lattitude -> Weather.

If what I said is confusing, please let me know. I can try to explain it more if needed.

Also, since I'm kinda new to this whole React.js and API thing, if there are any tips you would recommend, let me know. I would love to know any useful info throughout this journey.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using `postalcode` in your first URL but you've initialised it to an empty string. Which probably means the URL won't work as expected. (Same goes for your second URL).

Comment: @Andy so what do you recommend I format it as instead?

Comment: Well, you need it to be a postcode. How you supply that is up to you. Define it in the component; define it outside of the component and pass it in as a prop perhaps...

Comment: @Andy These terms are somewhat vague in my memory haha. I guess I will have to re-learn them. Thanks!, I'll try and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By dragging the second `axios` request inside the `then` of the first request, so you can use the response of the first request.

Or you can use `async` and `await` syntax.

For more resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @Andy I don't think so, I think the set state is an async operation, which will not execute until the current tick ends, would you please, provide an example to prove your theory.

Comment: Never mind, have a good day.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll go ahead and try this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
  axios.get(geocodingURL).then((geoCodingRes) => {
    // next call
    axios.get(weatherURL).then((weatherREs) => {
        // set your react states here
    })
  })
```